# Unable to connect to http://www.myurl.com/sitepath/something.rem

Tags: c#, .net, service, remoting

I'm maintaining a remoting service and am more familiar with wcf than I am with remoting. I have an application throwing an error when trying to connect to `myurl/myobject.rem` obviously those who are familiar with this technology know that the `.rem` object does not exist in the file system, so I can't see it. What can I check within the server to ensure this object is getting created and working properly?